# Android Studio Logcat Title Rename

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, android-logcat

In Android studio, I started a project with one name say "First Project" and later I renamed project as "Second Project", changed package name and everything to this new name but Logcat title (debugging process name ) shows previous process name as
com.example.app.first_project. I want it to be com.example.app.second_Project,
How do I achieve this, can someone help !!!

Comment: have you seeb tiy menifiest file and build.gradle file.

Comment: changing the app id in the build gradle worked

Comment: sounds good buddy.

Comment: yes...off course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `build.gradle (Module: app)` `applicationId` in `defaultConfig`:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app.second_Project"
        minSdkVersionhttps: 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```